# Automating selenium testcase on LinkedIn sign-in button?

Tags: selenium, xpath

Since the id/css/xpath is changing everytime the page is refreshed, I am not been able to build automated test case for the same.

```
public void test() throws Exception {
  driver.get(baseUrl + "/login/");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("li_ui_li_gen_1395990803469_0-title-text")).click();

  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Comment: Can you please paste HTML code snippet and error you getting for your code?

Comment: Does "www.linkedin.com/login/" exist?

Answer (score 1):

Xpath and CSS selectors are not definite therefore your statement that they change everytime is incorrect. You are using XPath and CSS selectors which are not suitable for this dynamically changing page.

You need to create XPath or CSS which cope with this, such as partial id, relative reference to a constant element, etc.

Without seeing the HTML, we can not suggest a strategy which will be suitable.